# Error: Typed property Illuminate\Http\Request::$password must not be accessed before initialization in file

Tags: php, laravel

when i try to send post request with postman i get this error Error: Typed property Illuminate\Http\Request::$password must not be accessed before initialization in file
C:\Users\Desktop\project\app\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Auth\CustomerAuthController.php on line 70
here is the request: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/register'

Register Function:

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users',
        'phone' => 'required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ], [
        'name.required' => 'The name field is required.',
        'phone.required' => 'The phone field is required.',
    ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['errors' => Helpers::error_processor($validator)], 403);
    }
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
    ]);

    $token = $user->createToken('ShopCustomerAuth')->accessToken;


    return response()->json(['token' => $token,'is_phone_verified' => 0, 'phone_verify_end_url'=>"Api/V1/auth/verify-phone" ], 200);
}
```

the body of post request:
{
"name":"user",
"email":"test@gmail.com",
"phone":"12345678",
"password":"12345678"
}

also line 70 is : 'password' => bcrypt($request->password),

Comment: Huh; that's a new one. Does your code work if you do `'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password'))` instead? I wonder if using the "magic" method that converts `password` from the request body (GET, POST, etc) into a parameter is messing with that.

Comment: well doing the -> input('password)) fixed it, i don't understand exactly why i faced this error , thank you for your help

Comment: That's good! Like I said, that's a new one, and I would have expected that you'd get the same error when accessing `$request->name` (or `email`, `phone`, etc.). I haven't seen that specific error before, similar ones yes, but "Typed property ..." is new to me. But regardless, `$request->password` is a "magic" method, and is basically shorthand for `$request->input('password')` (or `$request->get('password')`, etc.), so the code should be equivalent. Maybe someone else will be able to point you in the right direction, or if you find more, feel free to post a self-answer. Cheers! 

Comment: yes i'll look for any other explanaion, thank you again

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? and I am assuming that is a PHP error and not an IDE saying that?

Comment: i'm using php version 8.1.15 and php storm 2022.3.3